# jasperreports - exporting word is missing subreport field values but pdf is fine

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm exporting a report (from the JasperPrint object). It contains a subreport. If I export it as a pdf, all is fine. If I export it as word (docx), all the field values in the subreport are blank. Each row in the subreport in the docx is blank, although the correct number of rows are still shown (so the docx exporter does still get the subreport data). Field values in the master report still appear in the docx, just not the subreport. Static text (in the subreport table header row) also still appears in the docx subreport.

This is the same whether I export programatically or using the Save menu in the JRViewer control.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this? I tried setting the font to be really small as I know Jasper sometimes decides not to render if the text doesn't fit in the box, but this didn't solve the problem.

EDIT

I solved the problem by stepping through the code in JRDocExporter. I was showing a line (JRDesignLine) after each row in the subreport. This line spanned all columns. The JRDocExporter encounters the line before the text in the columns, sees it spans all columns, and as a result decides to skip printing all remaining columns. Removing the line brought back the missing text. This behaviour doesn't occur when exporting to pdf or viewing the report in the JRViewer control, just for docx export...

Comment: 1.does both of your report have the same encoding
2.I couldn't remember the exact fuction name but is your subreport height dynamic or static

Comment: Both generated from exactly the same JasperPrint object, which was created from the same JRDesign object, so I presume the encoding is the same (although I'm not sure which encoding you're referring to). The subreport height is set in the master report's design but the subreport in the doc takes a different height depending on the number of rows given to it (so in that sense, its definitely dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by stepping through the code in JRDocExporter. I was showing a line (JRDesignLine) after each row in the subreport. This line spanned all columns. The JRDocExporter encounters the line before the text in the columns, sees it spans all columns, and as a result decides to skip printing all remaining columns. Removing the line brought back the missing text. This behaviour doesn't occur when exporting to pdf or viewing the report in the JRViewer control, just for docx export...